# push_back() in std::vector<std::string> overwriting current string

Tags: c++, string, vector

I'm trying to implement an undo function when inserting a new line for a very simple text editor as a project for class. In the program, the column is where the cursor currently is, and the row is the current line the vector is on.

I was able to successfully create my "insertNewLine()" function which uses a `std::vector<std::string>` that is able to display the text to the screen. This is how I implemented it:

```
void Editor::insertNewLine()
{
    // get a substring
    prevLine = lines[row - 1];
    size_t tempSize = prevLine.size();
    int lengthOffset = getSubstringOffset(tempSize, (column - 1));
    std::string cutTemp = prevLine.substr((column - 1), lengthOffset);
    lines[row - 1].erase(column - 1);
    // after incrementing, row and amount of lines, initialize the new row
    row++;
    numberOfLines++;
    column = 1;
    lines.push_back(cutTemp); // insert substring into new line
}
```

Here is an example of what the current output looks like this (where | is the cursor):

```
hello world|    (user enters hello world, column = 11, row = 1)
hello|world     (user moves cursor to column 5, still on row 1)
(user presses button that calls insertNewLine())
hello 
|world          (splits where the cursor is to a new line, cursor begins at column 1)
```

Now, I am able to undo any other command, but when trying to undo a new line, I need to have the cursor return to the previous column, and push the word back where it originally was. I tried implementing that by doing this:

```
void Editor::undoNewLine()
{
    std::string source = lines[row - 1]; // save current line
    lines[row-1].clear(); // clear current line
    row--; // revert up one row
    numberOfLines--; // revert amount of lines
    lines.push_back(source); // append
}
```

With this function, I **expected** the output to look like this (from the example above):

```
(user presses a button that calls undoNewLine())
hello|world
```

But, the problem is, this is the output I get from the current code:

```
(user presses a button that calls undoNewLine())
|world
```

Essentially, using push_back(source) overwrites whatever was originally there and brings the cursor to the front. I tried to increment column to the original position it was in before the undo stage, however, this didn't work either. I just ended up with this output:

```
(user presses a button that calls undoNewLine())
world|
```

So how should I try and implement this undo function? Any tips or ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Something like `lines.back() += source;` perhaps?

Comment: You need to concatenate the two lines. You're not doing that.

Comment: @Barmar Do I pull both out, concatenate, then write over the new line?

Comment: @user657267 Unfortunately, the original text (hello) from the example remains, and the text I need to push back up ends up being deleted :[

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your solution, you're erasing the previous line's content (hello) with the call to clear(). Instead, just append the current line. The string class makes this easy:

```
lines[row-1] += lines[row];
```

After that you can remove the current line with [vector::erase](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/).

**Note**
Be aware that this is might be inefficient, since all the lines below need to be repositioned. 
If this does become an issue you can switch to std::list but then you lose random access to your lines.

Comment: No prob! And without more info I'm not sure. Maybe the cursor is no set correctly on undo? Or the line count?